How to get an existing scoped instance of a Blazor App with BlazorWebView?
I have a Blazor App, which creates an instance of "MyClass" through serviceCollection.AddScoped(). Within my Blazor App I can inject this instance.
But now I want to access this instance from my BlazorWebView (e.g. in MAUI, WPF, WinForms, etc.).
serviceCollection.AddScoped<MyClass>();

...

blazorWebView.Services.GetService<MyClass>();  // returns a new instance instead existing one

If I use "AddSingleton()" it is working of course, but how do I get the scoped instance of MyClass created by my Blazor App?
Expected result: The already created instance from Blazor App

That's not how it works. If you add a service as scoped you will get a fresh instance. Why do you need the same instance ? I guess it's about managing some state.
